Max power on potentiometer
Why didn’t power on R3 reach its maximum value when it was at 0 Ω?
I mean the formula is p=i/r. if R3 approaches 0, wouldn’t the power become infinite? But when I tested the potentiometer with different values in the circuit, the highest power occurred at 5 Ω (middle point). What’s the reason for this?
Is there a logical mathematical explanation?



I mean the formula is p=i/r.

No.
The formula is \$ P = I^2R \$.
You can derive this from \$ P = VI \$ (volts &times amps) by replacing \$V\$ using Ohm's law. \$P = (IR)I = I^2R \$.
Now it's clear that as \$ R\ \text{->}\ 0\$, \$ P\ \text{->}\ 0\$.

yes sorry i wrote it wrongly, i was meaning the formula of p=v^2/r. but i still didnt get the part why the max power is occuring when R3 is 2.7 kohm.

@louisa if R3 goes to zero, then V across it also goes to zero because of the voltage divider rule relating voltages across R2 and R3 (or more accurately, between R3 and the thevenin equivalent of the network driving it).

You can find the point at which power is maximized by writing an equation for the power in R3 as a function of R3.
Then differentiate that equation and set the result equal to zero and solve for R3.
That will be a maxima (or minima in general, but in this case we know power is always > 0 in a resistor). Also we know power is 0 at R3 == 0 and it would be 0 if R3 = open, and it is non-zero in-between.
As the other answers indicate it's about 2.7kΩ, not 5Ω (or 5kΩ, if that was what you meant to write).

The potentiometer can be considered a variable voltage divider, with the condition that the sum of the resistances that compose it is constant and equal to the nominal value of the potentiometer. In this way it is easy to treat it in the calculations relating to the network. See the following photo:


The question has a hint that says you don't need Thevenin or Norton calculations. However, imho, it is easier to solve this problem by first finding a Thevenin equivalent for the circuit consisting of just V1, R1 and R4.
Here is the circuit without R3.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The open circuit voltage of node Out is just
\$V_{oc} = 3\frac{10}{10+1.8} = \frac{30}{11.8}\$
The current through node Out when it is shorted to ground is just
\$I_{sc} = \frac{3}{1.8}\$.
The Thevenin equivalent resistance is just
\$R_{Th} = \frac{V_{oc}}{I_{sc}} = \frac{\frac{30}{11.8}}{\frac{3}{1.8}} = \frac{30\cdot1.8}{11.8\cdot3} = \frac{18}{11.8}  \$
So, the Thevenin equivalent circuit is

simulate this circuit
Now we add R2 and R3 back into the circuit.

simulate this circuit
Now \$R_{th}+1.2 k\Omega\$ is just
\$\frac{18}{11.8} + \frac{1.2\cdot11.8}{11.8} = \frac{32.16}{11.8} \approx 2.725 k\Omega\$

simulate this circuit
Then, by the maximum power transfer theorem, the maximum power will be transferred to R3 when R3 is set to
\$R_{max\_power} = \frac{32.16}{11.8} \approx 2.725 k\Omega\$

You don't see every day the effects of an infinite power released in some device, do you?
In theory, you get an infinite power when you connect an ideal voltage source with 0 ohm resistor. You don't have an ideal voltage source near R3.
To understand the particular circuit, you need to look at it as an non-ideal source (V1 + R1 + R2 + R4) and a load (R3).
The complex "source" now happens to have ~2.5V voltage and ~2.7kOhm internal resistance. It is well-known that you get maximum power when the load resistance is equal to the source internal resistance. Your R3 can do 2.7kOhm so this is where your max power will be.

Indeed, calculating the Thévenin resistance is the most direct way to solve this problem: $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R1}+\frac{1}{R4}}+R2 = 2725.42\Omega$$

thank you for clearing out but it says dont use thevenin calculation as in condition so how would i found this with only using ohms law and power equation

If using the Thevenin (capital T) calculation is not allowed then you should state that in your question. What are you allowed use?

Made with microcap v12
R= 0 Ohm * I^2 gives 0  ... V^2 / R = infinity gives 0 ...
Max power in R3 occurs for \$ R3 =\$ ~ \$2726 \$ Ohm ...

Maple sheet


thank you... but please explain it without any spice programme. beacause i need to explain this without simulating

Just state the equation of power vs resistor R3, then "derive" this function about R3. The solution of this equation gives the value of R3 for a "maximum". Just do it as @Francesco or @ Spehro did.
